# Any good way to declare method as `return this`?

Tags: java, design-patterns, generics, java-7, crtp

Something like this:

```
class C {

    typeof(this) foo() { return this; }

}
```

Well, I know it's impossible in Java 6, so I'll be glad to hear if I can do it in Java 7.

**EDIT**

This should be useful for chaining method calls, and avoid to create temporary local variables, like this:

```
class Entity {

    typeof(this) refresh();

    typeof(this) clone();

    typeof(this) detach();

}

class FooEntity extends Entity {

    @Override
    typeof(this) detach() {
        fooLink21.removeRef(this); 
        bar39.detach(); 
        return this; 
    }

    void doSomeInteresting() {}
}

fooEntity.clone().detach().doSomeInteresting();
```

and lot more.

I deem it should be very easy to add this function to compiler, well maybe I should hack into openjdk or gcj maybe?

BTW, I had never succeeded to rebuild the openjdk.

Comment: Are you trying to avoid overriding the method in every subclass?

Comment: Why wouldn't you declare an Interace and make your method to return a subtype of the interface.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish? There's nothing preventing an object from returning "this," although why you'd do it is limited to a few scenarios (primarily fluent builders, IMO.)

Comment: `<T extends C> T foo() {return this;}` is that what you want? Hard to determine from the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you would use generics it might look a little bit like this:

```
class Parent<C extends Parent> {

   public C getMe (){
      return this;
   }
}

class Sub extends Parent<Sub> { }
```

It might work, but I wouldn't suggest writing code like this. It's bad design...

Comment: As you said, it's a bad design, which force you to add type parameter to all classes.

Comment: Classes actually used by client code needn't have type parameters, as in this example. (I'd make `Parent` abstract.)

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there's any way to do this, in either Java 6 or Java 7. Adding it would not be easy - i think the return type would be what's called a 'dependent type', and that's something from a far more complicated type system than Java has at present.

Gressie's answer about adding a type parameter to the base class is the only way to get close to what you want, as far as i know.

However, if you were prepared to use a helper function, you could do it without a type parameter on the class:

```
abstract class Entity {
    public static <T extends Entity> T detach(T entity) {
        entity.detach();
        return entity;
    }
    protected abstract void detach();
}
```

You could then say:

```
import static Entity.detach;

detach(fooEntity).doSomeInteresting();
```

That's pretty clunky, though.

Comment: Agree, I didn't expect Java 7 to support it, though. +1 the static helper is a good idea.

Comment: I thought Gressie's idea was better, but hey, whatever works for you.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know much about Java (Second year SD student using primarily C#/C++), but you may want to look at Generics. If they are what I think they are in relation to C++, C#, they are like Templates, where you can write methods that return a Template type.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generics_in_Java

Answer (score 1):

From what it looks like you are doing, why not use a constructor? It also looks like you may be asking how to return a method? If so:

You can return a method in Java. I highly suggest you don't and consider alternatives to this practice. Have a look at  [java.lang.reflect](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/AccessibleObject.html) ; provides access to methods, fields and constructors. Java is not 'meant' to deal with first-class functions. If you DO decide to do this, be prepared for a lot of catch statements...